# Transforming an unkown phase into unkown bit values on bell states

Tags: gate-synthesis, bell-basis

Consider the state $|\Psi^\pm\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|01\rangle \pm |10\rangle)$.

The $|\Psi^\pm\rangle$ state is a bell state up to an unkown phase.

I am looking for a sequence of single-qubit operations "shifting" such an uncertainty over the bit values, rather than to the phase. Is it possible?

Formally I am looking for an operation $U = U_1\otimes U_2$ such that (e.g.):
$$U|\Psi^\pm\rangle = \frac{1}{2}(|00\rangle + |01\rangle + |10\rangle + |11\rangle).$$

Comment: The unitary transformation that you wrote down is mapping two orthogonal states $|\Psi^{\pm}\rangle$ to the same state $\frac{1}{2}(|00\rangle + |01\rangle + |10\rangle + |11\rangle)$, and therefore cannot exist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lorenzo mentioned in the comments, your final equation is probably missing something, as it maps two states to the same one.

If your goal is to have a transformation such that the phases are all positive, you can use $U_1=H$ and $U_2=ZH$. Indeed, let us first apply $H$ on the first qubit of $\left|\Psi^\pm\right\rangle$:
$$H_1\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|01\rangle\pm|10\rangle\right)=\frac12\left(|01\rangle+|11\rangle\pm|00\rangle\mp|10\rangle\right)$$
We then apply $H$ on the second qubit:
$$H_2\frac12\left(|01\rangle+|11\rangle\pm|00\rangle\mp|10\rangle\right)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(|00\rangle-|01\rangle+|10\rangle-|11\rangle\pm|00\rangle\pm|01\rangle\mp|10\rangle\mp|11\rangle\right)$$
For $\left|\Psi^-\right\rangle$, this gives the following state:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(-|01\rangle+|10\rangle\right)$$
While for $\left|\Psi^+\right\rangle$, this gives the following state:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|00\rangle-|11\rangle\right)$$
You can then apply a $Z$ gate on the second qubit if you want all the phases to be positive.